# How can I stop movement while airborne?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have recently begun working on a game for a uni project and will visit this site probably a lot while encountering problems. This time it's a small but annoying problem.

I am doing a 2D sidecroller so I used the template for it to get me started. I already put in the input for attacking and want that the character stops moving when he does the attack animation. On the ground it works wonderfully, but while airborne the character doesn't completely stop in the air, but is slowly decending during the animation. And I want that the character stops completely.

Here is the [Jump Handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2Zs1.png) from the 2d sidescroller template.

[Here is the event tick and where the animation update is called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWR7T.png) (Ignore the attack counter stuff, doesn't influence)

[Here is the Animation update code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35nA8.png) and the "Stop Movement Immediately" node. It has to be said that I am doing what I learned from a tutorial.

As the name implies, the node should stop movement, which is does in the X Axis, but not completely in the Z Axis. I tried it by saving the location of the Player Character when he attacks while in the air but either I couldn't get the code right or it doesn't work like that.

I would be thankful for advice with this (rather petty) detail.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is strictly while falling, try setting the gravity to 0 while attacking, create an Event in the animation that fires up when it's finished and then capture it to set the gravity back to the original value.

Comment: I already solved it in a way but your suggestion sounds pretty good. I will try it